# can't work with BufferedInputStream and BufferedReader together

Tags: java, sockets, bufferedreader, bufferedinputstream

I'm trying to read first line from socket stream with BufferedReader from BufferedInputStream, it reads the first line(1), this is size of some contents(2) in this content i have the size of another content(3)

1. Reads correctly... `( with BufferedReader, _bin.readLine() )`
2. Reads correctly too... `( with _in.read(byte[] b) )`
3. Won't read, seems there's more content than my size read in (2)

I think problem is that I'm trying to read using `BufferedReader` and then `BufferedInputStream.`.. can anyone help me ?

```
public HashMap<String, byte[]> readHead() throws IOException {
    JSONObject json;
    try {
        HashMap<String, byte[]> map = new HashMap<>();
        System.out.println("reading header");
        int headersize = Integer.parseInt(_bin.readLine());
        byte[] parsable = new byte[headersize];
        _in.read(parsable);
        json = new JSONObject(new String(parsable));
        map.put("id", lTob(json.getLong(SagConstants.KEY_ID)));
        map.put("length", iTob(json.getInt(SagConstants.KEY_SIZE)));
        map.put("type", new byte[]{(byte)json.getInt(SagConstants.KEY_TYPE)});
        return map;
    } catch(SocketException | JSONException e) {
        _exception = e.getMessage();
        _error_code = SagConstants.ERROR_OCCOURED_EXCEPTION;
        return null;
    }
}
```

sorry for bad english and for bad explanation, i tried to explain my problem, hope you understand

file format is so:

```
size1
{json, length is given size1, there is size2 given}
{second json, length is size2}
```

_in is BufferedInputStream();
_bin is BufferedReader(_in);

with _bin, i read first line (size1) and convert to integer
with _in, i read next data, where is size2 and length of this data is size1
then im trying to read the last data, its size is size2
something like this:

```
byte[] b = new byte[secondSize];
_in.read(b);
```

and nothing happens here, program is paused...

Comment: @GeorgeCan you please explain your case via input file example? Like you  have an input file because it is same for Java socket, file or other source, and you want what kind of output? If you explain via this way it will be more clear for us.

Comment: Please edit your question with this information, it is hard to read from comments.

Comment: I have edited queston

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create one `BufferedReader` ***_bin*** and `BufferedInputStream` ***_in*** and read a file both of them, but their cursor position is different so second read start from beginning because you use 2 object to read it. You should read size1 with _in too.

```
        int headersize = Integer.parseInt(readLine(_in));
        byte[] parsable = new byte[headersize];
        _in.read(parsable);
```

Use below readLine to read all data with `BufferedInputStream`.

```
    private final static byte NL = 10;// new line
    private final static byte EOF = -1;// end of file
    private final static byte EOL = 0;// end of line

private static String readLine(BufferedInputStream reader,
            String accumulator) throws IOException {
        byte[] container = new byte[1];
        reader.read(container);
        byte byteRead = container[0];
        if (byteRead == NL || byteRead == EOL || byteRead == EOF) {
            return accumulator;
        }
        String input = "";
        input = new String(container, 0, 1);
        accumulator = accumulator + input;
        return readLine(reader, accumulator);
    }
```

Comment: @GeorgeIt read the file line by line, use BufferedInputStream, read until readed byte not equal to newLine(asci code 10).

Comment: ah recursion ? there is readByte, i think there should be readLine

Comment: The first sentence of this answer is meaningless. There are so many things wrong with this code it would require a separate answer to list them all. For a start you aren't checking the result returned by any `read()` call. -1

Comment: @EJPPlease specify what is the meaningless and give source about it also please tell me what is the wrong about the code because i already use this function, it will be great for me to learn the missing points on it.

Comment: Meanignless is meaningless. It doesn't have parts. I've already told you at least one thing that's wrong with the code. I'll give you another: a byte value of -1 read into a buffer does not indicate EOF. A third problem: don't use recursion as an iteration mechanism.

Comment: There is code there and explanation too, you just write meaningless, it is not a consultant or professional approach. It will be better to specify it and so i can learn this is the aim of this site.

Comment: You can't 'specify' meaninglessness. It's meaningless. The problem with using two buffered streams/readers isn't about positions, it is about lost data. You haven't employed me professionally or as a consultant, and you haven't addressed my other comments.

Comment: @George Don't post code in comments. You can see for yourself that it's completely illegible. You also forget to state *why* you posted that code. But testing for `c != 0` doesn't have any apparent purpose, and, like this poster, you're not testing for EOS correctly.

Comment: @EJPI will appreciate if we can chat at chat rooms, i want to explain my sentences which are tagged by you meaningless, i didn't try to be aggresive just try to learn.

Comment: @erhun You should explain it *here,* where everybody can see it instantly, or better still edit your answer, but you can save your breath. It's wrong. There is only one position, and that's the position you're up to in the underlying data source.

Comment: @George That is correct. But that doesn't mean you should edit other people's incorrect answers accordingly. If you have a correct answer of your own, post it.

Answer (score 1):

> can't work with BufferedInputStream and BufferedReader together

That's correct. If you use any buffered stream or reader on a socket [or indeed any data source], you can't use any other stream or reader with it whatsoever. Data will get 'lost', that is to say read-ahead, in the buffer of the buffered stream or reader, and will not be available to the other stream/reader.

You need to rethink your design.

Comment: @EJBWhat is the difference between Socket and file in java, when i use BufferedInputStream?

Comment: @erhun From the point of view of the caller, none. Why do you ask?

Comment: @EJPSimple i don't know:) Acceoding to my knowledge there isn't any difference, i don't want to argue with you maybe you misudertand me, i want to learn.

Comment: @erhun If you have a question you should post it as a question. Posting questions here in comments to other answers to other questions isn't what this site is for. It's not a forum.